# Append JavaScript array data into div

Tags: javascript

I have the following JavaScript array data:

```
[{'id:1'},{"info":"Name"}"]
[{'id:2'},{"info":"LastName"}"]
```

How do I loop through this and insert the data into a div? I tried something like this,but no success:

```
for(var i=0; msg.length<i; i++){
    $('#results_box').append(msg[i].id);
    $('#results_box').append(msg[i].info);
}
```

Comment: You have your loop condition backwards, it should be:

    for(var i=0; i<msg.length; i++){

Comment: Also I think your JSON isn't constructed the way you intend:  all your objects have either 'id' or 'info' but never both.

Comment: yes they have both they are rows from database

Comment: The sample data you've posted isn't [valid JSON](http://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: yes maybe there is some error i type it manual

Comment: could you tell me how ta add new line in this code something like br in php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct your JSON to proper format:

```
var array = [{id:1,info:"Name"},{id:'2',info:"LastName"}]
```

then:

```
for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++)
{
    $('#results_box').append('<p>' + array[i].id + '=' + array[i].info + '</p>');
}
```

html

```
<div id="results_box"></div>
```

[Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/luqo/ysjq3hrc/)